# Port 443 build failed in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

I cannot build my spring boot application on port 443 port , but able to build on 8443 port for ssl. for the https I need to build the application on 443 port.
below is the error on 443 port

```
2020-04-05 11:55:54.567 ERROR 15565 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.wathiq.rabbitmqconsumer.Application.main(Application.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:278) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1038) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:229) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1035) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some parts of your exception are missing, I guess.

They would say, that the port is **already used** by another application (tomcat/nginx/traefik ...).

If the port is under 1024, please refer to this question ans answer:

https://serverfault.com/questions/610117/failed-to-bind-to-0-0-0-0443

> You need to be root (superuser) to bind to ports under 1024. That's why 9443 works, but 443 doesn't.

In your case it's 8443.